# rxjs6 map `this` always `MapSubscriber` when use pipe

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs

i'm try to use `pipe` in rxjs with `map`

my code is below down.

```
Service.js
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

getFunction(){
    return this.http.get(someurl, { params: parameter })
    .pipe(map(this.extractData), cathError(catchFunction));
}

extractData(res: HttpResponse<any>){

   console.log(this) <<<<< here is problem. this value always `MapSubscriber` type.
}
```

the problem is extractData function in `this`.

if i didnt set second parameter (aka thisArg) this value must be set undefined.

but, thisArg always set `MapSubscriber` type even i didnt insert second parameter in map function.

in reference https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map

could you please help me? why this call set `MapSubscriber` typs?

Comment: pipe((res) => this.extractData(res)) or pipe(this.extractData.bind(this))

Comment: I don't see you use `map` anywhere. You forgot to wrap it into the operator.

Comment: @IngoBürk sorry. that was my mistake. i correct my source